# Teradata Masking - Retain all chararcters at position 1,4,8,12,16 .... in a string and mask remaining characters with 'X'

Tags: function, teradata, mask

I have a requirement where I need to mask all but characters in position 1,4,8,12,16.. for a variable length string with 'X'

For example:

```
Input string - 'John Doe'
Output String - 'JXXn xxE'
```

SPACE between the two strings must be retained.

Kindly help or reach out for more details if required.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe an external function would be best here, but if that's too much to bite off, you can get crafty with `strtok_split_to_table`, `xml_agg` and `regexp_replace` to rip the string apart, replace out characters using your criteria, and stitch it back together:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('this is a test of this functionality', '(.)', '\1,') AS fullname FROM Sys_Calendar.calendar WHERE calendar_date = CURRENT_DATE)
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE((XMLAGG(tokenout ORDER BY tokennum) (VARCHAR(200))), '(.) (.)', '\1\2')   , '(.) (.)', '\1\2')
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        tokennum,
        outkey,
        CASE WHEN tokennum = 1 OR tokennum mod 4 = 0 OR token = ' ' THEN token ELSE 'X' END AS tokenout

    FROM TABLE (strtok_split_to_table(cte.fullname, cte.fullname, ',')
        RETURNS (outkey VARCHAR(200), tokennum integer, token VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS d
) stringshred
GROUP BY outkey
```

This won't be fast on a large data set, but it might suffice depending on how much data you have to process.

Breaking this down:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('this is a test of this functionality', '(.)', '\1,') AS fullname FROM Sys_Calendar.calendar WHERE calendar_date = CURRENT_DATE)
```

This CTE is just adding a comma between every character of our incoming string using that `regexp_replace` function. Your name will come out like `J,o,h,n, ,D,o,e`. You can ignore the sys_calendar part, I just put that in so it would spit out exactly 1 record for testing.

```
   SELECT 
        tokennum,
        outkey,
        CASE WHEN tokennum = 1 OR tokennum mod 4 = 0 OR token = ' ' THEN token ELSE 'X' END AS tokenout

    FROM TABLE (strtok_split_to_table(cte.fullname, cte.fullname, ',')
        RETURNS (outkey VARCHAR(200), tokennum integer, token VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET UNICODE)) AS d
```

This subquery is the important bit. Here we create a record for every character in your incoming name. `strtok_split_to_table` is doing the work here splitting that incoming name by comma (which we added in the CTE)

The `Case` statement just runs your criteria swapping out 'X' in the correct positions (record 1, or a multiple of 4, and not a space).

```
 SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE((XMLAGG(tokenout ORDER BY tokennum) (VARCHAR(200))), '(.) (.)', '\1\2')   , '(.) (.)', '\1\2')
```

Finally we use `XMLAGG` to combine the many records back into one string in a single record. Because `XMLAGG` adds a space in between each character we have to hit it a couple of times with `regexp_replace` to flip those spaces back to nothing.

So... it's ugly, but it does the job.

The code above spits out:

```
tXXs XX X XeXX oX XhXX fXXXtXXXaXXXy
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill .. I tried to run your code but saw the below error. SELECT Failed. 9134:  STRTOK: Varchar Inkey exceeded the max. allowed inkey length. Redefine UDF.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a solution, but then @JNevill inspired me with his idea to add a comma to each character :-)

```
SELECT
   RegExp_Replace(
      RegExp_Replace(
         RegExp_Replace(inputString, '(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?', '(\1(\2[\3(\4', 2)
                     ,'(\([^ ])', 'X')
                  ,'(\(|\[)')
   ,'this is a test of this functionality' AS inputString

tXXs XX X XeXX oX XhXX fXXXtXXXaXXXy
```

The 1st RegExp_Replace starts at the 2nd character (keep the 1st character as-is) and processes groups of (up to) 4 characters adding either a `(` (characters #1,#2,#4, to be replaced by `X` unless it's a space) or `[` (character #3, no replacement), which results in :

```
t(h(i[s( (i(s[ (a( (t[e(s(t( [o(f( (t[h(i(s( [f(u(n(c[t(i(o(n[a(l(i(t[y(
```

Of course this assumes that both characters don't exists in your input data, otherwise you have to choose different ones.

The 2nd RegExp_Replace replaces the `(` and the following character with `X` unless it's a space, which results in:

```
tXX[s( XX[ X( X[eXX( [oX( X[hXX( [fXXX[tXXX[aXXX[y(
```

Now there are some `(`& `[` left which are removed by the 3rd RegExp_Replace.

As I still consider me as a beginner in Regular Expressions, there will be better solutions :-)

Edit:

In older Teradata versions not all parameters were optional, then you might have to add values for those:

```
   RegExp_Replace(
      RegExp_Replace(
         RegExp_Replace(inputString, '(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?', '(\1(\2[\3(\4', 2, 0 'c')
                     ,'(\([^ ])', 'X', 1, 0 'c')
                  ,'(\(|\[)', '', 1, 0 'c')
```

Comment: Thanks Dieter .. when I tried to run your code I am seeing the following error .. "Function RegExp_Replace called with an invalid number or type of parameters" .. Could you help on this please?

Comment: @Sandesh: I edited my answer, hopefully it's running now

Comment: Hi Dieter .. Thanks so much .. the code worked , i had to make a small change as below .. sel RegExp_Replace(
      RegExp_Replace(
          RegExp_Replace('Neburchadnezza', '(.)(.)?(.)?(.)?', '(\1(\2[\3(\4', 2,0,'c')
                     ,'(\([^ ])', 'X', 1,0,'c')
                  ,'(\(|\[)', '', 1,0,'c');

Comment: @Sandesh: Running pre-TD15? There have been some changes in the RegEx syntax since then, of course without notice :-)

Comment: Yes Dieter .. I am running TD 14.10 ..  Also Dieter I am new to regular expressions there are a few more masking techniques that I need to develop .. Could you help me out with the below as well. 1) Passport Number Ex A1234567 - I need to keep the first character and mask the remaining as 'X' (AXXXXXXX)   2) Customer Phone Number - 98765432 : I need to mask the first 4 characters as '1' and remaining characters untouched (11115432)  3)email ID - davidchan@yahoo.co.uk , I need to mask all characters to 'X' and leave '@' and '.' untouched. Please kindly help me out with these 3 scenarios.

Comment: sorry for email id i need to mask as follows DAVIDXXXX@XXXXX.XX.XX (@ and '.' should remain as is)

Comment: There are lots of resources regarding RegEx, simply search *regex for ...*, but there are lots of dialect, Teradata is usually compliant with PCRE. Password: `RegExp_Replace(x, '.', 'X', 2, 0, 'c')`, can be done without RegEx, e.g. `RPad(Substr(x,1,1),Char_Length(x)-1, 'X')`. Phone: `RegExp_Replace(x, '....', 'XXXX', 1, 1, 'c')`. Email: `RegExp_Replace(x, '[^.@]', 'X', 6, 0, 'c')`, but seems like you want to keep the first name, of course this is not possible.